# How can I change the content of an element plus vuejs component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

I need to change the content of [element plus components](https://element-plus.org/en-US/).

I tried using `<template>` and `<slot>`, but without success.

```html
<ElInput v-model="form.name" placeholder="Nome">
  <template>
    <input class="intro-x login__input form-control py-3 px-4 block"
      type="text"
      autocomplete="off"
      tabindex="0"
      placeholder="Nome"
    >
  </template>
</ElInput>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass some specific style to your component, you will need to use `input-style` as [shown here](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/input.html#input-attributes). There is nothing similar to `input-class` so far, so you're stuck with something like this

```html
<template>
  <el-input
    v-model="form.name"
    :input-style="{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: '4rem' }"
    type="text"
    autocomplete="off"
    tabindex="0"
    placeholder="Nome"
  >
    <template>
      <input />
    </template>
  </el-input>
</template>
```

There are [no other slots](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/input.html#input-slots) related.

Meanwhile you can always *hack* the whole thing and style it with your own CSS as like this

```html
<style scoped>
:deep(.el-input__inner) {
  background-color: teal;
  border: 2px solid coral;
}
</style>
```